# Is it possible expose Saml2Constants.AuthenticationScheme?

Tags: itfoxtec-identity-saml2

I want to have different cookie name, but re-write Saml2ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddSaml2 and Saml2ResponseExtensions.CreateSession seems not very good just for change cookie name,

so it will be better to expose schema name and we can set it in appsetting.json.

Answer (score 0):

You are right is is currently not possible to set the cookie name in the `Saml2ServiceCollectionExtensions.AddSaml2` method. You are welcome to du a pull-request adding the feature.